# unsafe mix of xxx and bool in operation warning only when comparing value to TRUE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

I have a library that is implemented in C (C89 compatible). It defines a bool data type `bool32`. It also defines the boolean literals `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
#ifndef TRUE
# define TRUE  (0 == 0)
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
# define FALSE (0 != 0)
#endif

typedef uint32_t bool32;
```

C code like the following compiles without warning:

```
bool32 h = TRUE;
if(h==TRUE){
}
if(h==FALSE){
}
```

the same code in a cpp compiles with the following warning:

> 1>[filename/line): warning C4805: '==' : unsafe mix of type 'bool32' and type 'bool' in operation

But only for the `TRUE`comparision. the `FALSE` comparison does not produces a warning.

I also checked the preprocessed files to ensure that the above definition of `TRUE` and `FALSE` is used and not another one. This look ok.

Does anybody have an explanation why the warning occurs only on `TRUE` and how to avoid this warning? And another Question: Why does the Compiler in C-Mode does not warn?

Comment: It think it's simply because `bool` is an 8 bit value and `bool32`  is a 32 bit value. But you are right it's strange that the warning occurs only for the TRUE comparision.

Comment: Never compare against a literal Boolean. It's recursive madness. After all, the result of `h==TRUE` is *itself* a Boolean, so surely you must compare that to `TRUE` now? Just write `if (h)` and be done. Yes, I realize you probably have a huge codebase full of such comparisons so this doesn't help, I just wanted to mention it so perhaps somebody else *stops* creating a new such codebase. Never compare against Boolean literals.

Comment: @unwind i am with you with this opinion. But Coding rules enforce this in C code. Has something to do with Misra -.-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the warning because comparing an integer to a `bool` is bug-prone.

Consider the following:

```
bool32 x = 3;

if (x == FALSE) {
  printf("x is false\n");
} 
else if (x == TRUE) {
  printf("x is true\n");
} 
else {
  printf("x is neither true nor false!\n");
}
```

Output:

> x is neither true nor false!

Note that this is a problem regardless whether TRUE/FALSE are integer or bool, it's just that the compiler cannot correctly detect it when TRUE is an integer.

The problem exists because there are several integer values that are considered true. There is only one value that is considered false, `0`, so there can be no mixup there.

Comment: So why no warning with the comparison against false? `if(h==FALSE)` does not warn.

Comment: `0` is the only value that is considered false. All non-zero values are considered true, not just `1`. So the problem only exists for comparisons with TRUE.

Comment: and why does the c-compiler does not warn?

Comment: The compiler gets the preprocessed code. If TRUE is defined as `1`, it will get `if (x == 1)`, and it doesn't know if it is a bare `1` or if it was the macro `TRUE`.

Comment: In C and C++ files the VC compiler he's using generates the same preprocessor output for the comparisons of `if(h==(0 == 0))` and `if(h==(0 != 0))`. Verified with `cl.exe /E /c`. Only a file saved as `.cpp` gives the warning therefore the warning must be linked to the C++ standard, or Microsoft got it wrong.